# Position and style ajax loader

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to position (always in page center for all devices) and style (color, size, etc.) my ajax loader gif. For position I use @media-queries and I am trying to specify a div id inside my javascript. I tried inline styling but that doesnt really work. Is my goal possible to do?

```
$("#list").html("<img src='/images/ajax-loader.gif' width='200'>");
```

Comment: You need to add more information/code about what you have and already tried (maybe the resulting HTML and CSS after the append). Have you tried centering with auto left and right margins?

Comment: @Joseph Young - my main problem is to define my ajax loader gif in above javascript so that I can apply my CSS positioning and styling code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing what you mean by "doesn't reall work", we're kind of guessing here. However inline styles should work just fine for centering

```
$("#list").html("<img src='/images/ajax-loader.gif' width='200' style='position:fixed; left:50%; top:50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);'>");
```

I would suggest moving this into a class in your css though:

```
.loader {
     position:fixed;
     left:50%;
     top:50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Then just apply it:

```
      $("#list").html("<img src='/images/ajax-loader.gif' width='200' class='loader'>");
```